# Why is my Canon 155A Speedlite not firing from the hotshoe of my Canon AE-1?

Tags: flash, film, troubleshooting, hotshoe-flash, hotshoe

The AE-1's hotshoe won't fire the flash from some reason. I have the shutter speed set to 1/60s and my aperture is set to A (auto). The test button on the 155A fires the flash as does shorting two of the hot shoe connectors, but the shutter button won't for whatever reason. I can see that the camera senses the the flash because the light meter is locked on the appropriate f-stop. But I have no luck getting it to fire the flash. Using the sync port on a different, non-hotshoe flash unit works but I have no way of testing a sync port on the 155A. I've also tried cleaning the hot shoe connections.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try using another flash in the hot shoe to see if the camera is functioning properly.  The AE-1 is an older camera but it has delicate electronics,  and the flash circuitry may have been damaged at some point in it’s lifetime. If the circuitry is damaged you can use the 155A flash with the “Canon Synchro Cord A” using the sync port.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem with a Canon AE-1 + Speedlite 155A—it would power up and flash via the test button but was never triggered by the camera—and solved it yesterday:

By removing the four tiny screws around the hot shoe connector, you can split the case on the Speedlite flash unit. Very quickly, I noticed that, of the several tiny wires that snake into the hot shoe connector, the *yellow* wire was split/broken. I was able to strip about 1/16" of wire on either end of the break, solder it, and then wrap it with a tiny piece of electrical tape. Once I managed to get the sides of the case back together and everything buttoned up, the flash unit began working correctly again and was automatically triggered by the AE-1.

NOTE: it is quite difficult to get the flash unit back together, once the various components have been bumped around. Can be done, obviously, but takes quite a bit of time and lots of patience to reassemble, especially without damaging any wires or connections in the process.